# AngularJS - How to access the isolated scope from the linking function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Consider the following directive example: [(Live Demo)](http://plnkr.co/edit/l9tD3vW4ADrm4UEncHrO?p=preview)

```
app.directive('phone', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      tel: '@'
    }, 
    template: '<div>{{tel}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.tel);   // undefined
    }
  };
});
```

which is used like this:

```
<phone tel="1234"></phone>
```

`tel` is accessible in the template, but in the linking function it is `undefined`. Why? How could I access the isolated scope from the linking function?

Comment: It seems like you are doing everything right here. I experienced similar problem when value that I put in attributes was gotten from Ajax request and at the time console.log called in `link` it was `undefined`. But this is diffidently not your case.

Comment: at least you can use `tel: '='`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't get interpolated before the linking function is done (I'm not sure why this is), but you have a couple of options:

```js
app.directive('phone', function($timeout, $interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      tel: '@'
    }, 
    template: '<div>{{tel}}</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      //Use $timeout service with no delay:
      $timeout(function(){
        console.log(scope.tel);   // 1234
      });

      //Use $watch - will get called every time the value changes:
      scope.$watch('tel',function(tel){
        console.log(scope.tel);   // 1234
      });

      //You can even use the $intrapolate service, this is basically what `@` does:
      console.log($interpolate(element.attr('tel'))(scope.$parent));

      // in your example tel isn't an expression but a constant so you could also do this:
      console.log(attrs.tel); // 1234
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since @ isolate scope can only pass strings, your only option is

`console.log(attrs.tel)`

"The @ local scope property is used to access **string values** that are defined outside the directive" - http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope